Symmetry in a matrix leading to symmetry in eigenvectors
In my Physics class recently, my professor gave us a trick to finding the eigenvectors in certain matrices and I am looking for a proof of it.
Claim:

Given a $3\times3$ matrix with $1,2$ symmetry, the three eigenvectors of the matrix will also have $1,2$ symmetry: two even and one odd.

Here $1,2$ symmetry in the matrix means that if we switch the 1st and second row and then switch the 1st and 2nd column the matrix will remain unchanged. $1,2$ symmetry in the eigenvector means we can switch the first and second entry in the vector and the result is a multiple of the original. The vector is considered odd if when we switch these two entries the resulting vector is the same except for a factor of -1 and even when the switching truly has not effect on the vector.
Putting this into mathematical terms I have the following:

Let $\phi(i)$ be defined by $\phi(1)=2$, $\phi(2) = 1$, and $\phi(3) = 3$ (or more generally any permutation of order two on the set $\{1,2,3\}$). Then, if we have a matrix such that $A_{ij} = A_{\phi(i)\phi(j)}$. Then two of the eigenvalues will have $v_{i} = v_{\phi(i)}$ and one of the eigenvectors will have $v_{i} = -v_{\phi(i)}$ for all $i$.

Example:
I feel as though this is best shown through examples rather than my explanation above so I will give the following examples of matrices with $a,b$ symmetry and their resulting eigenvectors will also have the same $a,b$ symmetry.
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&4 \\ 2&5&2 \\ 4&2&1 \end{pmatrix}$$
has 1,3 symmetry and the eigenvectors
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \sqrt{2} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -\sqrt{2} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}  $$
also have 1,3 symmetry. The first one listed is odd while the latter two are even.
Thoughts:
I'm sure that this could be proved by showing a matrix of the form:
$$  \begin{pmatrix} a&b&c \\ b&a&c \\ d&d&e \end{pmatrix}$$
has eigenvectors of the form:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ -\alpha \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \alpha \\ \gamma \end{pmatrix}$$
but I am looking for a more insightful proof that I may be able to generalize to different size matrices and possibly different permutations of the indices.

Given a real symmetric $n\times n$ matrix $A$, let $P$ be an $n\times n$ permutation matrix such that $A = PAP^{-1}$, or equivalently, $PA = AP$. When $n=3$ and $P$ is the permutation matrix associated to the permutation $(1,2,3)\to(2,1,3)$, this is precisely the $1,2$ symmetry you are talking about. In particular,
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Since $P$ is real symmetric and commutes with $A$, they are simultaneously diagonalizable. The eigenvectors of $P$ can be easily found to be
$$
(0,0,1)^T,\quad (1,1,0)^T,\quad (1,-1,0)^T.
$$
The first two have eigenvalue $1$ and the last one has eigenvalue $-1$. Together, they generate precisely the vectors that you mentioned at the end of your post.

Since you mentioned physics class, I’m guessing you came across this in quantum mechanics where $A$ is the Hamiltonian. The above procedure captures how symmetries organise the spectrum of the Hamiltonian in terms of representations of the symmetry group. The underlying reason for this is that any symmetry operator commutes with the Hamiltonian, so they can be diagonalised simultaneously.

Suppose that $A$ is a matrix with this symmetry.  We can encode what this symmetry means in a computationally convenient way by saying that $M=PAP^{-1}$ where $P$ is the permutation matrix
$$P = \begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Now, assume that $Av=\lambda v$.  Then we have that $(PAP^{-1})(Pv)=P(\lambda v)=\lambda Pv$.  So if $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then so is $Pv$.  But $Pv$ is just taking $v$ and swapping the first two rows.
Assuming that $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, this tells us that swapping the first two rows of an eigenvector gives us another eigenvector in the same eignespace, which means it must be a multiple of our original vector, so $Pv=\mu v$ for some $\mu$.  But $P$ only has eigenvalues $\pm 1$, where $1$ has multiplicity $2$ and $-1$ has multiplicity $1$.  Thus, all the eigenvectors have $P$-symmetry, two being even and one being odd.
If we don't have distinct eigenvalues, then things can fall apart a little, as $A$ might not even be diagonalizable. For example, consider
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}3&-1&2\\-1&3&2\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}.$$
However, if $A$ is diagonalizable, then even though not all eigenbases will have the property of the question, there will exist one that does.  This is a consequence of another proof (similar to the one given by Pranay).

Here is a second approach that requires a nice result from linear algebra: If $AB=BA$, then $A$ preserves the eigenspaces of $B$ and vice versa (so if $Av=\lambda v$, then $A(Bv)=\lambda (Bv)$).
Our symmetry condition can be written as $AP=PA$, and so $A$ sends $P$-eigenvectors to $P$-eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue.  The eigenvectors of of $P$ are of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$, which have eigenvalue $1$, and $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ -a \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, which have eigenvalue $-1$.
Unfortunately, since $A$ only needs to preserve these eignespaces, this approach lets us construct counterexamples to your professor's claim in the case that $A$ has repeated eigenvalues (one of which was listed before).  But it turns out that if two matrices commute and they are both diagonalizable, then there exists a basis that is simultaneously an eigenbasis for both matrices.  This doesn't mean that when $A$ is diagonalizable that any eigenbasis will work (e.g., if $A=I$, then you can take any basis you like, and most will not have $P$-symmetry).

Key takeaways if you want to generalize.  First, we can view symmetries of a matrix $A$ as a matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}=A$.  Second diagonalizable matrices which commute with each other can be simultaneously diagonalized.  Third, in any group $G$ which acts on a thing $X$ (be it a set, a vector space, a topological space, whatever), then $(ghg^{-1}).gx=g.(hx)$, and if we further have $ghg^{-1}=h$ and $g.x=x$, then $h.(gx)=gx$.  Or, in other words, if conjugating by $g$ preserves $h$, and then $g$ maps $h$-invariants to (possibly different) $h$-invariants.  This is a bit weaker than what we used, but it generalizes more readily to different contexts.
